# How can I get a not underlined email address, written in the To textbox, in mailItem.To?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, mailitem

[image]

I can get the registeredmail@mail.com mail address in the To property in the mailItem object but I can't get unregisteredmailadres@mail.com that is not underlined in the To property of the mailItem object.

[image]

`mail.Recipients` with protag not found in all mails.

How can I directly get everything written in mailItem.To

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook caches data and doesn't propagate your changes to the Outlook object model immediately or in the opposite side - changes made via OOM programmatically until you switch to another field in the UI or just re-open an item.

Also you may try to call the `Save` method to get the item saved to the store with all changes. Most probably you'll have to move the focus to another control on the UI.

Answer (score 1):

The `Recipients` collection is not updated until you tab out of the To edit box.